# [Android studio]- After configuring Flutter and dart sdk path, when I click apply, it just erases the path I entered

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, configuration, sdk

I started Android studio(Flutter & Dart) two days ago, and I've been getting errors again and again, but I overcame the previous errors but today after I tried to configure the Flutter and Dart SDK and pressed 'apply', the path just disappears(erases itself). I tried to search this on the internet, but all of which it gave me was not related to this error... Is this a bug? Should I re-install android studio?

**This is when I entered the path...**

[image]

**this is when I pressed apply**

[image: this is when I pressed apply]

**UPDATED**

Already got answer

I had same issue, when tried to install latest version of Android Studio, already fixed it, ex. `Flamingo` version

Comment: Is there any issue after running `flutter doctor` on terminal?

Comment: since I can't select an sdk... I get ````flutter is not recognized as an internal or external command,```` when I type flutter doctor

Comment: Try `flutter doctor` on terminal / cmd.  If is not `recognized`   follow installation process. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Comment: I installed it, pasted the path in environment variables, and then tried to enter the path in the android studio when I got the error and when I first got this error I even tried re-installing flutter.

Comment: Did you restart the computer after installation process? also, what is your current output from cmd by running `flutter doctor` and if you are on Windows, you can type `where flutter` .

Comment: When running flutter doctor, I get the error ````'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,```` and (i am in windows) I typed ````where flutter```` and I got this as a reply ````INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).````.

Comment: I have my Flutter Folder stored in C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\flutter.

Comment: Do you have java installed ? can you share how you have set the path on `envoirnment`

Comment: I have installed Java and I know I have installed it because I had an error related to it yesterday. In the environmental variables, I have pointed to the flutter and dart's 'bin' folder in the path variable.

Comment: While you are facing `'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` means there is something wrong on installation process

Comment: Nothing went wrong with the installation of flutter because even the day before yesterday, it was working fine.

Comment: And in the first picture, there is an error at the bottom of the screen... I searched the internet for it but it seems that no one else had this error

Comment: Now I am going to completely delete my environment variables, android studio, flutter and dart and install it from the beginning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by re-installing one of the earlier versions of android studio, Flutter and I finally restarted my computer(I'm on Windows 10 home) and It really worked great.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: but I did not write any code nor refer to any documentation... I did it myself.

Comment: @TechLord Which version of android studio were you on when it didn't work and to which version did you revert?

Comment: I had same issue, when tried to install latest version of Android Studio, already fixed it, ex. `Flamingo` version